# Rounding to unit above with C#

Tags: c#, rounding

How to I round a decimal upwards to the nearest int.

i.e.

```
1.2 ---> 2
5.6 ---> 6
79.9 ---> 80
85.01 ---> 86
```

(int)Math.Round(count / (decimal)rows, MidpointRounding.AwayFromZero)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

`Math.Ceiling` is your friend